# Problem with encoders in Subtitle Editor

Tags: editor, subtitle

When I try to open a .mp4 with subtitle editor I get the following message
`GStreamer-plugins missing`.

The playback of this movie requires the following decoders which are not installed:

*H.264 decoder*

I tried "bad" plugins for gstreamer, but I got nothing, tried

`sudo apt-get install h264enc`, also nothing.

gst-inspect |grep 264 output

```
'videoparsersbad:  h264parse: H.264 parser
x264:  x264enc: x264enc
rtp:  rtph264depay: RTP H264 depayloader
rtp:  rtph264pay: RTP H264 payloader
h264parse:  legacyh264parse: H264Parse
typefindfunctions: video/x-h264: h264, x264, 264'
```

Comment: What is the output of `gst-inspect |grep 264`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Open terminal and run the command:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/gstffmpeg-keep  
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install gstreamer0.10-ffmpeg
```

Comment: already installed

Comment: I edited my answer @opossum,..please have a try

Comment: still nothing it does't work

Comment: Again edited my answer....@opossum

Comment: it didn' work either

Comment: Edit your question and provide output of `gst-inspect |grep 264`

Comment: Please try command in my answer

Comment: it show the following  'WARNING: erroneous pipeline: no element "ffdec_h264" '

Comment: Ok,...My last edit

Answer (score 1):

On a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (which I should note came with VLC already installed), I found all I needed to get video working on SubtitleEditor was:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

This has the advantage of not needing need a PPA, compared to the accepted answer.

Considering what I found in other AskUbuntu answers, I want to note I don't have `h264enc` nor `gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` nor `libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0` installed: `apt list --installed` + `grep` does not show them, as I only have the `good`, `bad` and `ugly` gstreamer plugins. Installing the libav package alone solved SubtitleEditor's complaints about the H.264 and MPEG-4 decoders.